# Excel 2016 Finding Table within Worksheet used in Formula

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have inherited a workbook and I am trying to fix a "#N/A" issue I am having in a column of cells. There is allegedly, based on the formula: `=IF(ISBLANK(G140),"",VLOOKUP(G140,**Accts**!A:C,3,FALSE))` a table or sheet called "Accts" but, I can't find it in the Name Manager or see it as hidden sheet. Does anyone know of a different way  to find this table or sheet?

Comment: It may be [Very Hidden](https://www.excel-university.com/make-an-excel-worksheet-very-hidden/) which means you will need to navigate to the VBE to unhide it, using the properties window in the VBE

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks for that. I see the sheet Accts, but when I View Code, there is no code in that sheet.

Comment: You need to go to the properties of that very hidden sheet, change the visible property to visible.  Then you will be able to see the sheet and it contents in excel.